# how to select last 12 months name and year without using tables using sql query?

Tags: sql, sql-server

how can i select last 12 month name  using current time. without using any table 
if current month is October then i want the result as

```
month    year
oct      2011
nov      2011
dec      2011
jan      2012
feb      2012
mar      2012
apr      2012
may      2012
jun      2012
jul      2012
aug      2012
sep      2012
oct      2012
```

i don't have any table in Database for this.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
SET LANGUAGE English;

WITH R(N) AS
(
SELECT 0
UNION ALL
SELECT N+1 
FROM R
WHERE N < 12
)
SELECT LEFT(DATENAME(MONTH,DATEADD(MONTH,-N,GETDATE())),3) AS [month], 
       DATEPART(YEAR,DATEADD(MONTH,-N,GETDATE())) AS [year]
FROM R
```

Answer (score 5):

```
declare @start DATE = '2011-10-01';


 with CTEE(date)
AS
(
    SELECT @start
    UNION   all

    SELECT DATEADD(month,-1,date)
    from CTEE
    where DATEADD(month,-1,date)>=DATEADD(month,-10,@start)
)
select Datename(month,date) from CTEE
```

Comment: it did not works when i run ur sql in sql server 2005. what i miss. need explain. thanks

Comment: @Thomas my friend thats becuase DATE is not supported in sql 2005. only datetime.

Answer (score 2):

```sql
SELECT STR(MONTH(DATEADD(mm, number, GETDATE())), 2) AS MonthNum, 
DATENAME(month, DATEADD(month, MONTH(DATEADD(mm, number, GETDATE())), 0) - 1) AS MonthNames
FROM master.dbo.spt_values
WHERE (name IS NULL) AND (number BETWEEN 0 AND 11)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use MVJ's F_TABLE_DATE:
http://www.sqlteam.com/forums/topic.asp?TOPIC_ID=61519